# We want to get all the records in Database using HQL in terms of Spring and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

```
Here i tried 2 write cod 2 get list from Mysql Database using spring nd Hibernate.
```

**But problem is here that how initialize **org.hibernate.Session se** **through "applicationContext.xml" file by bean class....**

```
public void getList(**Session se**){
    String liststudent="from StudentList stud";
    Query q=se.createQuery(liststudent);

    List<Object> list=q.list();
    for(Object obj:list){
        Object studarr[]=(Object[])obj;
        System.out.println("Data at Zero Index"+studarr[0]);
    }
}


As here property name **template** has been initialized by the ref template.
Is there any way to initialize Session se.


<bean name="mydao" class="dao.MyDao">
    <property name="template" ref="template"></property>

</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

using your context.xml file

define sessionFactory

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <!--define other properties...mapping files
</bean>
```

define hibernateTemplate

```
<bean id="template" class="*HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

then

```
<bean name="mydao" class="dao.MyDao">
   <property name="template" ref="template"></property>
</bean>
```

NOTE: the class package has been ommitted